# Multi match query and the scoring calculation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have couple documents in the index, and 2 of them are

```
{
          "id" : "c0706549-d06c-4043-8086-1b4b3ec1ef95",
          "title" : "Google Pixel XL",
          "memory" : "4GB",
          "quantity" : 3
}
{
          "id" : "23ecaecd-6b3f-4592-b79f-f46a20157221",
          "title" : "Google Pixel XL",
          "memory" : "6GB",
          "quantity" : 1
}
```

And for the query

```
{
  "query": { "multi_match": { "query": "pixel xl 6gb", "fields": ["title", "memory"] } }
}
```

I get the response

```
{
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "c0706549-d06c-4043-8086-1b4b3ec1ef95",
        "_score" : 2.4280763,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "c0706549-d06c-4043-8086-1b4b3ec1ef95",
          "title" : "Google Pixel XL",
          "memory" : "4GB",
          "quantity" : 3
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "23ecaecd-6b3f-4592-b79f-f46a20157221",
        "_score" : 2.4280763,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "23ecaecd-6b3f-4592-b79f-f46a20157221",
          "title" : "Google Pixel XL",
          "memory" : "6GB",
          "quantity" : 1
        }
      }
```

But I expect that the document with the `memory` field `6GB` will be on top, can you please advise why this happens and how to fix it?

Index mapping

```
  {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "memory" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          },
          "fielddata" : true
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "synonym_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Index settings

```
{
        "index" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "filter" : {
                    "synonym_filter" : {
                        "type" : "synonym",
                        "synonyms" : [
                            "laptop, notebook"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "analyzer" : {
                    "synonym_analyzer" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "standard",
                        "filter" : ["lowercase", "synonym_filter"] 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Elasticsearch version 7.7.0

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this locally and I am getting much higher score(~2X) for a document containing the `6GB` and if you note carefully in your case, both the document has exactly the same score (2.4280763), that means both of them has exactly the same relevance and its just the order in Elasticsearch response that is different.

**Think of it, you need to sort the numbers 1,2,3,1 then 1,1,2,3 will be the order 
it doesn't matter which `1` comes before or after.**

Also, you need to provide your mapping and index configuration(number of shards) and elasticsearch version(as older version uses `tf/idf` while the new one uses `BM25`) for score calculation.

I tried this on ES 7.7 version and as mentioned earlier with my mapping and your sample data got 2X better score.

**Index mapping**

```
{

    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title" : {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "memory" : {
                "type" : "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index your 2 docs**

```
{
  "title" : "Google Pixel XL",
  "memory" : "6GB"
}

{
  "title" : "Google Pixel XL",
  "memory" : "4GB"
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "pixel xl 6gb",
            "fields": [
                "title",
                "memory"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "multma",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.6931471,  --> note this
        "_source": {
          "title": "Google Pixel XL",
          "memory": "6GB"              --> 6 GB one has a better score and coming on top
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "multma",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.36464313,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Google Pixel XL",
          "memory": "4GB"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you please try to index first 4GB and than 6GB? Cause this is the order how they were inserted in my case

Comment: @user13674325, just now I did what u suggested and even after indexing first `4gb` doc, it comes later in the search result, can you tell me which version of ES u are using ?

Comment: I use Elasticsearch version 7.7.0

Comment: @user13674325 ok, so my version and your version is same, I see you are using your own custom analyzer, can you show mapping and setting of your index?

Comment: @user13674325 just tried with your setting and mapping and by indexing `4gb` doc first still getting its score lower than 6 GB

Comment: @user13674325 i guess you are missing some more info, I would suggest delete the index, recreate and index your doc again and search and let me know if still its an issue

Comment: @user13674325 hope you are safe, did you get a chance to try the things I suggested in last comment and let me know if you still facing issue?

Comment: @user13674325 any luck